# How can I filter remote results without multiple ajax requests with Select2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

The following code returns a remote data set for a [select2](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2) select control:

```
 $("#select-band").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a band",
        allowClear: true,
        //minimumInputLength: 3,
        ajax: { 
            url: myurl.baseURL+'/items/itembands',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term // search term
                };
            },
            results: function (data) { 
                return {results: data};
            },

            dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop"
        }
    });
```

I was previously only returning data if the user had typed 3 characters but now want to return all data and filter the returned results data without making further ajax requests.

The size of the JSON response is approximately 45kb so not huge but also not insignificant. I'm finding that if I try to filter the results by typing in the input, a new ajax request fires and my search result is not highlighted correctly.

Comment: When you say 'return all the data' how much data are we talking about? This may not be a good idea if it's a couple of hundred Kb in size.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan see updated question. Its approx 45kb.